# Can't bind touch event on the element not in document tree (in iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, backbone.js

currently I'm developing a webapps on both iOS and Android.

I'm trying to capture the touch event on iOS, but I can't get it down before I populate my element to document tree, here are the codes.

```
var test1 = $("<div>").css({
width: "300px",
height: "300px",
"background-color":"#ff00ff"
});
var test2 = $("<div>").css({
width: "100px",
height: "100px",
"background-color":"#ffff00"
});

$(test1).append($(test2));

$(test1)[0].addEventListener("touchstart",function(){
  alert("listen addEventListener");
});
$(test1).bind("touchstart",function(e){
  alert("listen bind");
});
$(test1).on("touchstart","div",function(e){
  alert("listen on");
}); 

$("body").append($(test1));
```

on my iPad, it doesn't firing any touch event if bind these callback before test1 append under body.
but on my Android phone work.

if I change listening event from touchstart to click, it also work in iOS.

so is there anything I miss about touchevent on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

If that's your problem, I don't see why you don't add the event listeners after the append! I even don't see why you shouldn't append first test1 and after that test2

Comment: eh, cause I'm using Backbone.js to bind the events in my webapp. Backbone.js bind the event before it append to the DOM tree. this test1 and test2 just for testing purpose. I know it could be solve by binding the event after the element append, but I still curios why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround to this issue is to add touch event listeners on 'DOMNodeInserted' and remove them again on 'DOMNodeRemoved'-Event.

Answer (score 0):

I lost about half a day banging my head on this as well and ended up with a hack to hook up events after elements are in the DOM.  I'm using Marionette as a helper library for Backbone... for that, here's my 'fixer' code.

```
// Normally, Marionette will register event handlers before elements are
// added to the DOM.  For touch-related events, Safari on iOS does not
// like this... no error message, but the event handler will never be
// invoked.
//
// Our workaround for this is to provide a default implementation for 
// 'onShow'
//
Backbone.Marionette.View.prototype.onShow = function() {
    this.delegateEvents();
}
// onShow is invoked by Marionette after views are added to the DOM...
// but only if they are added to the DOM via a call to
// region.show(view).  For most views, this is sufficient.  However,
// for ItemViews within a CollectionView, there is never such a call.
// For this case, we have a workaround within a workaround: have the
// default onShow implementation for CollectionView loop over all of
// its children (the ItemViews) and call onShow on them just as the
// Marionette.Region would have done.
Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.prototype.onShow = function() {
    this.delegateEvents();
    if (this.children) {
        $.each(this.children, function(i, itemView) {
            itemView.onShow();
        });
    }
}
```